How do I find out if I have bitcoins I purchased
I remember when they used to call people and sell Bitcoin over the phone I remember purchasing some and either 2008 or 2009 I ended up getting five of them with an actual coin sent to me how do I find out if they kept track of that


In 2008 or 2009

The first Bitcoin was mined on or after 3rd January 2009, so you can't have bought any in 2008
Mike Caldwell created the first Bitcoin physical coin in 2011. So you can't have bought any physical coin-like Bitcoin token in 2009.
It must have been 2011 or later.


how do I find out if they kept track of that

By contacting them directly.
However, I doubt any of the businesses that sold physical coins in 2009 (were there any that early?) are still trading.
Even if they still exist, they may not be able to help. As an example see https://www.casascius.com/TandC.aspx

Company warrants and represents that [...] all digital copies securely destroyed.
[...]
Coins that are destroyed or stolen are permanently unrecoverable. If your Casascius Coin is lost, stolen or damaged, they cannot be replaced or re-issued.


Useful sources

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Casascius_physical_bitcoins
What is a physical bitcoin token?

